# Creating "Categories" to show on a PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a student database, and I'm trying to show different metrics based on a student's score **range** in a PivotTable. Specifically (this is a simplified example, so don't worry about the content) I want to show this in my pivot:

```
 StudentGPACat | Avg Post-Grad Salary
 3-3.2         | 64,323
 3.2-3.4       | 71,225
 3.4-3.6       | etc
 3.6-3.8       | etc
 3.8-4.0       | etc
```

So I want the rows in my pivot table to show the range the student's average score falls in.

In order to generate that metric, right now, I did 2 things:

(1) Added a new column in my master table in PowerPivot called [avgGrade] that shows the value of the [TableAvgGrade] calculated field from the "Grades" table for each student (i.e., each row in the master table)

```
=CALCULATE([TableAvgGrade],
    FILTER(Grades,Grades[studentID]=Master[studentID]))
```

(2) Created a new column [StudentGPACat] in PowerPivot and the formula goes:

```
=If([avgGrade]<3,"3",
If([avgGrade]<3.2,"3-3.2",
If([avgGrade]<3.4,"3.2-3.4",
If([avgGrade]<3.6,"3.4-3.6",
If([avgGrade]<3.8,"3.6-3.8","3.8-4.0")))))
```

This feels bulky and computationally expensive. Is there an easier way to create these ranges to use as rows in my PivotTable?

EDIT: made some edits to clarify my question
EDIT2: type

Comment: is it a an Excel PivotTable or a PowerPivot one ? Also you did not tag the Excel version.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is the appropriate pattern for creating this sort of column. If you're concerned about the gnarly nested IF()s, you can replace with a SWITCH(), which is just syntactic sugar for nested IF()s, but what you've posted is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

In a PivotTable  (I don't know with PowerPivot), if you use a numeric value as a `Row Label`, you can Right click the field, choose `Group`, define the `Starting at` value, `Ending at` value and `By` step, and you will get an equivalent result quite easily.